# How can I clear unwanted music off of my iphone?

Tags: music.app

My iphone shows me a variety of songs that I no longer want to have on it. iTunes does not show those items under 'Music' under the phone. I sync -- they're still there. What do I need to do to get rid of them? Contrary to various sources on the internet, sliding to the left on the song does not offer deletion, but starts to play it.

What's particularly vexatious is that I've got some Van Halen song on here. I've never seen it before. It does not show up on my Mac in itunes at all. I guess a child of mine might have purchased it.

I tried disabling icloud and setting up music syncing from itunes, and ran a sync, but that song and other undesirables persists.

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92477/how-can-i-remove-songs-from-the-music-app-on-my-iphone/92480#92480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These songs are iTunes purchases that are available for download but not currently on your iPhone. To hide these:

**Settings > iTunes & App Store > Show All: Music = *OFF***

Answer (score 1):

You can delete them directly on your phone by sliding the song to the left on the songs list.

Comment: No I cannot. Sliding to the left just slides back to the list of 'albums, songs, artists'.

Comment: Because the problem songs were 'icloud' songs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ever had icloud enabled, you will see all the music you ever purchased in itunes. Even if you turn icloud *off*, that music will persist in your music app. The only way I found to get rid of it was to go to the itunes store in itunes and hide all the unwanted music. Once I had done that, they finally disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use some 3rd party app like iFunbox to directly delete the song. Don't sync your device though.

Answer (score -2):

Here’s how:

- Go to http://itunes.com/soi-remove. This will launch your iTunes Application.
  Click Remove Album.
- Sign in with the Apple ID and password you use to buy from the iTunes Store.
- You’ll see a confirmation message that the album has been removed from your account.

Comment: How does this solve the problem described in the question?